# Variable blade , concatenar para generar un asset

Tags: html, laravel-blade, blade

tengo un archivo blade que recibe un objeto llamo "Routines" el cual recorro y quiero crear dinámicamente la url del asset para cada elemento, por ello hago lo siguiente

```
  @foreach ($routines as $routine)

      <tr>
         <td> <img id="definition-image" src="{{asset('assets/img/exercises/exercise'+ $routine->exercise_id +'.png')}}"> </td>
         <td> {{ $routine->name }}</td>
      </tr>

   @endforeach
```

Si hago un dd de routine tiene estos atributos

```
{#339 ▼
   +"exercise_id": 20
   +"name": "Cruces en polea"
```

Y la url que quiero construir seria esta
**assets/img/exercises/exercise20.png**

Gracias

Comment: En PHP se concatena con el símbolo de punto

Comment: Por otro lado ese código que error da?

Comment: Gracias BetaM....tenia el error al concatenar...1000 gracias

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al compañero @BetaM, estaba haciendo mal la concatenación.

Debe ser de esta forma

```
<td>
    <img id="definition-image" width="100" height="100" src="{{ asset('assets/img/exercises/exercise'.$routine->exercise_id.'.png') }}">
</td>
```